# Raphäel.js : image element get black border on IE 8, why?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, raphael

I am using [Raphäel.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) library.

I have a set of Raphäel image elements:

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

var appleImg = paper.image("apple.png", 10, 10, 30, 30); 
var orangeImg = paper.image("orange.png", 50, 50, 30, 30);
var pearlImg = paper.image("pearl.png", 100, 100, 30, 30);

var imgSet = paper.set();
imgSet.push(appleImg, orangeImg, pearlImg);
```

As you see above, I push all images to the set of `imgSet` .

Then, I add a mouse down event to the image set like following:

```
imgSet.mousedown(
    function(event) {

        imgSet.attr({opacity: .5});

            }

);
```

The mouse down event handler is intend to change all image to be 50% transparent.

The code above is working well on Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

But when I test the code on **IE 8**, I got **black border** on each image element, why?

(The 50% transparent is also showing on IE 8 which is fine, but why there is black border on each image element?)

**P.S.** 
I have thought may be it is because of the 50% transparency change on image which cause this IE problem, but after I commented out the line `// imgSet.attr({opacity: .5});`    I still got black border on each image.

Comment: Any luck fixing the issue? Is the reason really stated in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is due to the IE bug with semi-transparent images and alpha filter: http://solidlystated.com/design/ie-png-black-border-on-hover/

Comment: Hi, I still got the problem even I don't change the transparency of the images in my mouse down event handler

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the border for all images in IE? Maybe it has something to do with its default stylesheet.

As you can see [in the demos](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html) on the Raphael official site, there is no border around the rotating image, although it is generated using the `image` method just like yours.